# Power on does not work when display is closed

Tags: boot, power-management

Having a Samsung N230 Storm netbook runnning ubuntu 12.04
As I want to use only external devices (VGA Display, USB Keyboard, USB Mouse) and have the netbook acting as a "desktop" most of the time, I have the display closed.

**When hitting the "On button"** (even so its more a switch that I have to move slightly) **nothing happens. The system is not powering up.** As I was running Windows 7 Starter before moving to ubuntu with the same hardware being plugged and it was working (and I have not changed anything in the BIOS) **I must assume, that it is a setting within ubuntu that I got wrong.**

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Open Power settings and change the setting for **When the lid is closed** to **do nothing**.